# Factor Analysis - Assigning scores by row

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I run a factor analysis with `fa`, I obtained 8 factors (I will use only 5 of them, the ones with SS Loading >1), and now I would like to assign to each row (respondents of my survey) of my original dataset the score of each factor.

Where are the scores stored? How can I create five new columns and assign to each of them the factor score?

CorrMatrix is the Correlation matrix of the items (30x30 matrix)

```
fa.varimax<-fa(CorrMatrix,nfactors = 8,rotate = "varimax",fm="pa")
```

the original dataset counts 2994 respondents, one respondent each row

`item1 item2 item3 ... item30
     1     3     5 ...      4
     3     4     2 ...      5`

what I would like to do is to add at the end of the original dataset five new columns

```
factor1 factor2 factor3 factor4 factor5
score1i score2i score3i score4i score5i
score1j score2j score3j score4j score5j
```

for all the 2994 respondents

Comment: Please add examples of your data and desired output.  You should also include any code that you have tried.

Comment: updated the request, I hope now it will be more clear, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `psych` library as the question did not state.  The SS loadings are not directly stored in the factor-analysis, but can be calculated.

```
library(psych)

fa.loadings <- colSums(fa.varimax$loadings ^ 2)  # calculate factor loading
fa.loadings <- fa.loadings[fa.loadings > 1]  # filter factor loading
```

Reference: https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych253/tutorials/FactorAnalysis.html